# Cannot find the namespace for generic type "List"

Tags: c#, winforms, list, exception

I have a strange error and don't know how to solve that. I have a Form which gets opened by another (Main)Form. When I write

```
 List<String> valStoreAsString = new List<String>();
```

I get "The value or namespace List could not get found". My using directives are the following:

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

In the other Forms it works fine. What happened here?

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic` - You can find reference to any .net class by just searching on google for "msdn className". [Example for list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: it is not namespace BTW it is a Type which exists in the namespace mentioned by @Sayse

Comment: Ok thanks. That was fast. I searched around the Internet and also visited that site but it seems that I overlooked that! Thanks again! What a silly error...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: System.Collections.Generic  is referred by both forms?

Comment: No just by one of them. I copied the namespace but somehow I missed the .Generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following using directive to the list of usings.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

**Tip**

If you are using Visual Studio and if you don't know the namespace then type name of type (Case sensetive) in editor and then press `ctrl`+ `.` and select add using option and VS will add related using for you.

or you can right click on name of Type and select `Resolve` option and select `using ....` sub option.