# Type or namespace List<> not found

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Fairly new to C#, I'm trying to set two arrays, then join the elements of both these arrays into a list.
The code goes as follows:

```
using System;

namespace CMP_1002
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int a, b;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of first set:");                  //arrange first array's size
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] firstArray = new int[a];                                      //define first array

            for (int i=0; i<a ; i++){                                           //read and add each first array element
                Console.WriteLine("Enter element:");
                firstArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of second set:");                 //arrange second array's size
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] secondArray = new int[b];                                     //define second array

            for (int i=0; i<b ; i++){                                           //read and add each second array element
                Console.WriteLine("Enter element:");
                secondArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            List<int> union = new List<int>();                                  //define a new list for union

        }
    }
}
```

Yet I've tried all the conventional ways to define a list; this is taken from MSDN. Every time the error pops up claiming "The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The code is written in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Community Edition.

Comment: You need a using statement ...

Comment: You need to use the generic namespace.  `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: You are missing `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: `using System.Collections.Generic` maybe?

Comment: I mean, the error says *are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*. Maybe you are missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find the namespace for generic type "List"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759775/cannot-find-the-namespace-for-generic-type-list)

Comment: it helps to always always always Google the *actual error message*.  Faster and easier to learn from other people's mistakes.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you are missing a `using directive or an assembly reference`.

In this case, you are missing a using directive.  Add the following to the using section:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

In the future, if you get this error, you can look at the documentation for the class to determine what namespace and what assembly it is from.

For example, the generic list has the following information at the top of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> Namespace:System.Collections.Generic
>
> Assemblies: System.Collections.dll, mscorlib.dll, netstandard.dll

Comment: Well I checked in which directive List is in and it is under System and every time I specifically add the necessary directive it says that it is "unnecessary" and doesn't solve the problem. edit: hmm yes this one did it thanks a lot

Comment: Ah yes. `List` is in the System namespace, but the generic version of it `List<T>` is in a different namespace.

Comment: @Onthespot Put the `using` directive there. After that, you'll need to actually populate the `union` list. Right now it'll just be an empty collection.

Comment: Yeah this one did it.